# how to modify a comma separated list

Tags: jquery

i have a string which is coming as `1,2,3,4,5,6`

i want thee string to be as: `id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4&id=5&id=6` as in jquery, how can i modift the string like tis: the value i am getting is from the array as like this, i need to pass it to my href link so i can use it on my next page

```
var arr = [];
        $('input[class="allchecks"]:checked').each(function() {
          arr.push($(this).val());
        });
        alert(arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input[class="allchecks"]:checked').map(function(id) {
    return 'id=' + $(this).val();
}).join('&');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Array [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method:

```
arr.join('&');
```